# How do I write a Javascript variable back to text box it was entered into?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding some string handling to a page that handles scanning barcodes for entering data into forms.

My Javascript function takes in the string and manipulates it to read as a date, as I need it to.

I can't figure out how to populate the text field with the resulting tweaked string.

```
 for (i = 1; i <= itemcount; i++) {
     tempEXP = eval("this.document.all.form1.txtExpiration" + i + ".value");

     //code for Lombard GTIN Barcode Date Handling
     if (this.document.all.form1.hidClient.value == 393) {
         if (tempEXP.length > 11) {
             if (tempEXP.slice(0, 2) == "]C") {
                 tempEXP = tempEXP.slice(21, 27);
                 tempEXP = "20" 
                           + tempEXP.substring(0, 2) + "-" 
                           + tempEXP.substring(2, 4) + "-" 
                           + tempEXP.substring(4, 6);
             }
```

This grabs the value, evaluates and edits it.

I need to now post it back to the page.

Later in the function, post-validation, I try to use this to post it back:

```
    if ( answer == true )
{
    if(this.document.all.form1.hidClient.value == 393)
        {
            this.document.form1.inputbox.value = tempEXP;
        }
```

I have tried a few different methods as well, with no luck. Am I going about this all wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `document.all`?! Please stop writing code specifically for Internet Explorer 4/5.0 and read a JavaScript / DOM tutorial written this century. http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills

Comment: Word on the streets is "Eval is Evil", avoid using it unless you absolutely have to, say in a library.

Comment: You can avoid many browser inconsistencies by using a javascript library like jQuery or min-frameworks like [Zepto.js](http://zeptojs.com/)
What do you mean by "post it back" - do you only want to populate the text field with the resulting tweaked string `tempEXP`?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly right.

I can't go and implement any huge changes, which is why I'm sticking with all of the antiquated language.